# Need help understanding for loops

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

Currently I am learning Java and I am stuck at some for loops which I have no idea how they work.

The code looks like this:

```
int sum = 0, maximum = number[0], minimum = number[0];
for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
    sum += number[i];
    if (maximum < number[i]) { 
        maximum = number[i];
    }
    if (minimum > number[i]) { 
        minimum = number[i];
    }
}
```

So my questions are:

1. What does 
   `int sum = 0, maximum = number[0], minimum = number[0]` do? Does it make the loop start 
   from 0?
2. in the for loop, what does number.length; do?
3. What does sum+=number[i] do and why is the [i] needed?
4. Same in the if loops which check the maximum/minimum values, why is there [i] behind number?

Comment: There's no such thing as an "if loop".

Comment: http://www.learnjavaonline.org/ would be a good place to start

Comment: You should go through a basic tutorial.

Comment: 'If' is a statement, not a loop.

Comment: You should refer CS 101

Comment: @ArunkumarSharma Loops are also a type of statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 . What does int sum = 0, maximum = number[0], minimum = number[0] do? Does it make the loop start from 0?

(Note that this line has no effect on the for loop that comes next.)
This line initializes `sum`, `maximum` and `minimum` to `0`, `number[0]` and `number[0]` respectively.
Note that this line is a shorthand for:

```
int sum = 0;
int maximum = number[0];
int minimum = number[0];
```

> 2 . in the for loop, what does number.length; do?

`number.length` is the length of the array `number`, it is to say the number of `int` values stored in the array `number`.

> 3 . What does sum+=number[i] do and why is the [i] needed?

It increments `sum` of `number[i]`.
`number[i]` is the i-th `int` value stored in the int-array `number`. Here, `i` is called an *index*.

> 4 . Same in the if ... which check the maximum/minimum values, why is there [i] behind number?

Here also, `i` is an index to say that you want the i-th value in the array `number`.

(By the way, also consider

```
maximum = Math.max(maximum, number[i]);
minimum = Math.min(minimum, number[i]);
```

instead of the two `if` conditions.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, and yes, I meant for-loop. Was confused while posting it.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
int sum = 0, maximum = number[0], minimum = number[0];
```

Declares three variables (`sum`, `maximum` and `minimum`) of type `int` and initializes them with some values (`0`, `number[0]` and `number[0]` respectively.

`number` seems to be an array (probably an `int[]`), which means it holds multiple `int` values.

`number.length` simply returns the number of elements in `number`.

`number[i]` returns the element at position `i` in the array (just as `number[0]` returns the element at position 0, a.k.a the first element).

So most of your confusion seems to be caused by the lack of knowledge of what arrays are.

See [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) for a starter.

Comment: It could be interesting to point out that declaring several variables on a single line is not recommended, see the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-141270.html#2992)

Answer (score 1):

> What does int sum = 0, maximum = number[0], minimum = number[0] do?
>   Does it make the loop start from 0?

It declares 3 int variables (sum, maximum and minimum) + initializes them

> in the for loop, what does number.length; do?

It gets the length of the number array

> What does sum+=number[i] do and why is the [i] needed?

`sum += number[i]` can also be written as: `sum = sum + number[i]`
`+=` is called a preincrement. the `[i]` is needed because it refers to a certain index in the number array

> Same in the if loops which check the maximum/minimum values, why is
>   there [i] behind number?

Because you are getting the number at index `i` in the `numbers` array.

Answer (score 0):

the loop is a for-loop. If is a condition statement.

```
int sum = 0, maximum = number[0], minimum = number[0];
```

this creates and initializes 3 int variables: sum, maximum and minimum.

number.length is part of the end-condition for this loop. As long as i < number.length is true, this looop will be executed

number[] is an array

```
sum+=number[i]
```

this adds the value of the number[i] to sum 
[i] is the cell of an array - i gets a new number every loop:

```
int i = 0; i < number.length; i++
```

so it starts with 0, is incremented by 1 and this is done, as long as i is lower than number.length.

so `number[i]` will be `number[0]` in the first iteration of the loop, then number[1] then number[2] and so on

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean "for loop". Let's start with the syntax of a for loop.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
   your code here....
 }
```

The "`int i=0`" part declares a "phantom" integer variable, which means that it only exists in that if loop; when the loops ends the compiler "tosses away" that variable. The initial value of i is 0.

Then you have the part `;i < number.length;`. This part expresses that "run the loop until i reaches the length of array number.

Finally, "`i++`" defines the step length; how bigger(or smaller) i will be after each run. In this case i++ means `i = i + 1`.

So in summary. Your for loop starts with the initialization of a counter, then decides for how big a counter you want to run iterations and finally how much you'll increment this counter.

I have to note that these are one of the basic stuff and a book or a guide would be great for you to start. Otherwise you will have to as